# Alternative to Fick's law of diffusion?

Tags: thermodynamics, diffusion

Let's model a concentrate $C$ with a flux vector $\overrightarrow{J}$.

From first principle we can obtain the conservation law $\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + div \overrightarrow{J}$.

An adequate modelling of diffusion requires a modelling of the flux $\overrightarrow{J}$. The commonly used modelization is Fick's law for diffusion. It expresses the flux vector as $\overrightarrow{J} = -D \overrightarrow{\nabla} C$ with $D$ a diffusion coefficient (assumed constant here).

This gives us the classical heat-equation $\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = D \Delta C$.

This is all well and good but suppose that we are in dimension two and w put a Dirac of concentration at a point $x=0$, $y=0$ at time $t=0$. Also assume that $D=1/2$.

Then the solution is a multiple of the basic solution $f(x,t) = t^{-1} exp(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2t})$. So at time $t>0$ the concentrate has spread all over the space.

So, we have infinite speed of propagation which is clearly unphysical. In general this is not really a problem and so Fick law is widely used.

But, one may want to have a physically correct modelization of diffusion. What are the alternatives that exist? As I understand, it starts with Fick's law since the conservation law is a given.

Comment: In order to have a finite propagation, you must have a second partial derivative in time: $\partial^2/\partial t ^2$.

Comment: What would be an adequate modelization of diffusion of this kind?

Comment: Your initial conditions with a $\delta$ peak are unphysical as well, and the "infinite" concentration at the origin might be the cause of the fast initial propagation. You could try to start with a localised but finite initial concentration and check the spreading of the substance.

Comment: Do you really want to model this down to the point where the concentration is half a molecule per cubic meter?  As you said, in any practical situation, that would not be of interest.  I guess you could model it by using molecular dynamics calculations to track each individual molecule.  Is it really of interest or worth it?

Comment: It is well true that the dirac at the origin is unphysical. But it is what is called in mathematics a fundamental solution. If you have a more complex initial solution, you can integrate the initial condition and get it. But that is a technical point. The thing is even in the case of complex initial condition, you will find this unphysical infinite speed of evolution. Is there a reasonable modelization of diffusion that avoids this infinite velocities?

Comment: The heat conduction is also described with similar equation and there one knows that the second partial derivative term prevents infinite speed heat spreading. It becomes more like a wave equation with a front propagation. However, the diffusion coefficient being constant is also an approximation. Thus, non-linear phenomena may intervene in reality too.

Comment: This is a well-known problem also for thermal conduction; search for terms such as Catteneo, Maxwell-Catteneo, Catteneo-Vertotti diffusion

Comment: Thanks. I could find reference for Maxwell-Cattaneo diffusion. But Catteneo-Vertotti returns nothing on google.